# Android application using asp.net in server side

Tags: android

I want to develop an android application which collects data and send it to the server for further process.I need to use asp.net in the server side with MySQL database.Is it possible to implement  android client and asp.net server communication without using web services?

Could someone please help me!!!

Comment: Your requirement "send it to the server for further process" describes your question. No matter what the solution it will require some sort of posting of the data to the server and getting a response. (POST/GET). Boiling it down, web services in one shape of the other is your *best* solution if you want to send data captured on the Android and needing to be sent to a server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible. Android will see only JSON or XML , so if you communication format is JSON or XML then it is obviously possible.

SOAP format is one type of Webservice that's why it's not your answer.

Comment: What you are describing (I believe) is just some form of web service that accepts JSON/XML. JSON/XML is a data format (crudely put), not a communications method.

Comment: I am not telling that communication format. From android end we will POST or GET data in JSON or XML format. I just told that thing. I think now you will understand my poor English  .

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer!!! Is it right way to achieve client server communication without using any of the web services? Any suggestion?

Comment: Yes. you can just maintain the JSON or XML format in a right way. If my answer acceptable then please accept my answer. Thanks.